# Start Hadoop by ./start-dfs.sh and jps has namenode, but hadoop is still not available?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have successfully installed Hadoop on my server(ubuntu 16.04).As I was trying to start hadoop with ./start-dfs. Everything went well

```
songdian@sparkmaster~/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin$ ./start-dfs.sh
18/01/15 00:00:37 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting namenodes on [sparkmaster]
sparkmaster: starting namenode, logging to /home/songdian/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-songdian-namenode-sparkmaster.out
sparkworker1: starting datanode, logging to /home/songdian/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-songdian-datanode-sparkworker1.out
Starting secondary namenodes [sparkmaster]
sparkmaster: starting secondarynamenode, logging to /home/songdian/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/logs/hadoop-songdian-secondarynamenode-sparkmaster.out
18/01/15 00:00:52 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Here the jps shows the namenode(I have started spark also)

```
songdian@sparkmaster~/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin$ jps
27344 ResourceManager
31233 Jps
30753 NameNode
24919 Master
```

However,as I was trying to new a file on HDFS. There is an error says:

```
songdian@sparkmaster~/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin$ hadoop fs -mkdir /data
18/01/15 00:34:14 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
mkdir: Call From sparkmaster/10.12.3.2 to sparkmaster:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused; For more details see:  http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/ConnectionRefused
```

I am seeking where the problem is. And when I was trying to stop Hadoop, there is a clue.

```
songdian@sparkmaster~/local/hadoop/hadoop-2.6.0/sbin$ ./stop-dfs.sh
18/01/15 00:14:16 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Stopping namenodes on [sparkmaster]
sparkmaster: no namenode to stop
sparkworker1: no datanode to stop
Stopping secondary namenodes [sparkmaster]
sparkmaster: no secondarynamenode to stop
18/01/15 00:14:20 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
```

Besides, I have checked my worker node(sparkworker1), there is no datanode in jps.

```
songdian@sparkworker1:~$ jps
19861 NodeManager
18862 Worker
25262 Jps
```

I am sure I have configured `hadoop-env.sh, yarn-env.sh, mapred-env.sh, core-site.xml, hdfs-site.xml, mapred-site.xml`and`yarn-site.xml` right.

Anyone who can help me?

Comment: That first jps does not show a running datanode

Comment: Your datanodes are not running, check the logs for datanodes to see what is wrong. Or try to format your namenode and verify that version id of the namenode and datanodes are the same.

Comment: @Alex Yes I have verified and the problem has been solved